# Show process is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Problem 12.2 4 from Grimmett (Probability and Random Process):

> Let $(M,\mathcal{F})$ be a martingale with $M_0 = 0$ having differences $D_r = M_r - M_{r-1}$. Show that, $X_n = M_n^2 - Q_n$ is a martingale where $Q_n = \sum_{r=1}^n D_r^2$

My attempt,

\begin{align}
 & X_n = M_n^2 - Q_n \\
&\hspace{10pt} = M_n^2 - \sum_{r=1}^nM_r^2 - \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}M_r^2 + 2\sum_{r=1}^n M_rM_{r-1}; \quad (\text{since $M_0 = 0$ - for second term}) \\
&\hspace{10pt}  = M_n^2 - M_n^2 + 2\sum_{r=1}^n M_r M_{r-1} 
\end{align}
As a result, I think,
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1} + 2M_nM_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_{n-1} + 2M_{n-1}\mathbb{E}[M_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}+ 2M_{n-1}^2
\end{align}
*martingale property. This confuses me because I don't see if we can directly assume $M_{n-1}^2 = 0$ and/or if I've made some algebraic mistake. On the solutions, it writes:
\begin{align}
X_n = M_n^2 - Q_n = 2 \sum_{1 \le r < r \le n}D_rD_s.
\end{align}
However, I can't understand why that previous claim is valid. Any ideas/help or tips is very much appreciated. Thank you :),

Answer (score 2):

Define $D_0$ to be $0$. Then $ \sum\limits_{r=0}^{n} D_r=M_n$. Hence, $X_n=M_n^{2}-Q_n=(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n} D_r)^{2}-\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n} D_r^{2}=2\sum_{1\leq r<s\leq n}D_rD_s$ by just expanding the square.

To complete the proof you only need the fact that $E(\sum_{1\leq r<s= n}D_rD_s|\mathcal F_{n-1})=0$ which is easy from the martingale property of $(M_n)$.